# Elasticsearch subaggregation not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to perform aggregation on a `term` and then perform sub aggregation on the result test to filter the results on a date range. But  sub aggregation filter has no affect on the search response. The search response is always returning all the documents without applying `filter`.

For example:

```
TermsBuilder aggregationBuilders = AggregationBuilders.terms("form.id").field("form.id").size(0);
        aggregationBuilders.subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.filter("indexDate").filter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("indexDate").lte(date)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `filter` aggregations the other way around, i.e. as a top aggregation and then you add the `terms` aggregation as a sub-aggregation.

```
TermsBuilder formBuckets = AggregationBuilders.terms("form.id")
     .field("form.id")
     .size(0);

FilterBuilder dateFilter = AggregationBuilders.filter("indexDate")
     .filter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("indexDate").lte(date))
     .subAggregation(formBuckets);
```

I see in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36805072/elasticsearch-top-hits-aggregation-java-api-query), you have somehow "solved" this issue by moving the filter on `indexDate` to the query section. That will also work in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes i solved the filtering by making a bool query along with a range query. Now Filtering works and the aggregation on form.id also works but somehow top hits is not working as expected. Can you review that![link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36805072/elasticsearch-top-hits-aggregation-java-api-query)