# elasticsearch top hits aggregation java API query

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am running the below query and want to retrieve top hits per bucket. But I see multiple docs per bucket in few cases. I want only one document per bucket returned. Can some one review the query and suggest.

```
        SearchResponse sr=client.prepareSearch(versionIndexName).setTypes(versionIndexType).setQuery(Quer
    yBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("indexDate").lte(givenTime)))
               .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("form.id").field("form.id").size(0) 
                  .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.topHits("top").setExplain(true).setSize(1)
.setFrom((size*index)).addSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("indexDate")
    .order(SortOrder.DESC)).setFetchSource(true))).execute().actionGet();
```

STEPS in the query:

1. Filter by indexDate less than or equal to a given date.
2. aggregate based on formId. Forming buckets per formId.
3. Sort in descending order and return top hit result per bucket.

Comment: Not sure why you are getting more than one top hits even when specifying `setSize(1)`. Can you explain under which condition/bucket you're getting more than one doc?

Comment: I have two versions (v1 and v2) for form.id=1 with indexDate as 2016-04-22T16:02:32.738-07:00 for v1 and 2016-04-22T16:02:33-07:00 for v2. If i search by date 2016-04-22T16:02:33-07:00 i expect to see a bucket with only v2 returned in it because that is the closest to the searched date. But the bucket has both the versions. Let me know if my explanation is not clear.@Val

Comment: Does any one has any idea on the top hits query and why it is not working in my case?

Comment: Can you show what the value of `givenTime` is?

Comment: @Val givenTime is exact match to v2 time (2016-04-22T16:02:33-07:00).

Comment: @Val: Thanks for the reply. I am using ES 2.1.1 . And another thing i forgot to mention is i am running this against a child index . I mean to say this index is a part of parent and child mapping. Will it make any difference? For example consider, parent index name is "form" and type is "version", child index name is "form" and type is "versionhistory". So i am running this query against index name as "form" and type as"versionhistory". Does tophits aggregation behave differently in parent child scenario?